# XSL-FO Layout conditional information

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, antenna-house

I am working on layouting flight manuals using XSL-FO with Antenna House Formatter v6.3.

Much information is of the type *"If condition X do this and that, otherwise do something else"*. In the current case I have the following XML:

```
<crewDrill>
    <case>
        <caseCond>Hot inside:</caseCond>
        <if>
            <caseCond>Yes</caseCond>
            <crewDrillStep>
                <para>Adjust thermostat</para>
            </crewDrillStep>
            <crewDrillStep>
                <para>Open the window</para>
            </crewDrillStep>
        </if>
    </case>
    <crewDrillStep>
        <para>Enjoy life</para>
    </crewDrillStep>
</crewDrill>
```

The desired output for this XML would be:

[image: desired output for conditional statements]

Edit: So my concern is wether the desired output is feasible using XSLT to transform the XML into XSL-FO (including functionality in Antenna House Formatter) and, if so, what would be the proper way to approach the problem? The only way I could do this, given my knowledge of XSL-FO, would be to resort to using tables. Perhaps there is a better way.

Edit 2: As @Tomalak Points out it's really two questions - both how the XSL-FO structure could look like and also how the XSLT transformation could look like. My primary concern is how an XSL-FO structure representing the desired output could look like. Given a target structure, I will porbably be able to figure out the transformations. Sorry for unclear initial question and thanks to @Tomalak for clarifying my concern.

The XML-schema used stems from the S1000D 4.1 Crew schema

Comment: Okay so you have two questions here, and you should solve them one after the other. **Question 1**: Whether FOP XML document exists that will result in a PDF that looks like this. Answer: I have no idea. Maybe through some trickery with tables, maybe through SVG. Your first step should be to figure this out and write the according XML by hand, without using any XSLT.

Comment: The **Question 2**: Given that desired FOP XML, and some input XML, how would the XSLT look like that generates this? This question you should tackle when you have solved the first one. It's much easier than the first question, too. So once you know what target XML you want to create you should have little difficulty with getting something to work on your own.

Comment: I'd say the better way to do that would be to generate SVG, like mentioned by @Tomalak.

Comment: SVG would likely only be a good solution if the diagram is meant for one page. If a break is allowed inside the diagram, then tables (with a list) are a decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some XSL code for thought. It's not perfect but tweaking some of the borders and columns in the table could get you there.

NOTE: I added a single document element surrounding so I could test various cases.

This XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="document">
            <fo:root font-family="Arial">
                <fo:layout-master-set>
                    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="page"
                        page-height="11in" page-width="8in"
                        margin-top=".5in" margin-left="1in" margin-right="1in" margin-bottom=".5in">
                        <fo:region-body/>
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                </fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="page">
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" >
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
            </fo:root>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="crewdrill">
            <!-- whole diagram, put into a block -->
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="case">
            <!-- map to a table 2-row table, one for heading and one for the step(s) -->
            <fo:table>
                <fo:table-column column-width="12pt"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="12pt"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="12pt"/>
                <fo:table-column/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="prrportional-column-width(100)"/>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="6">
                            <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                <xsl:value-of select="caseCond"/>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="if">
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border-right="0.5pt solid black">
                    <fo:block text-align="right" margin-right="-1.5pt">◄</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding-left="-1.5pt">
                    <fo:block>►</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block>─</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid black" text-align="center">
                    <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                        <xsl:value-of select="caseCond"/>
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block><fo:leader/></fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border-right="0.5pt solid black">
                    <fo:block><fo:leader/></fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block><fo:leader/></fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:block><fo:leader/></fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border-right="0.5pt solid black">
                    <fo:block><fo:leader/></fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell font-weight="bold" text-align="center" number-columns-spanned="4">
                    <fo:block>- END -</fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="crewDrillStep[not(parent::if)]">
            <xsl:variable name="num">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::crewDrillStep) + 1"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <fo:table>
                <fo:table-body>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid black" text-align="center">
                            <fo:block font-weight="bold">No</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:block><fo:leader></fo:leader></fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                            <xsl:apply-templates>
                                <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell font-weight="bold" text-align="center" number-columns-spanned="5">
                            <fo:block>------ END ------</fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="crewDrillStep">
            <xsl:variable name="num">
                <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::crewDrillStep) + 1"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="para">
            <xsl:param name="num"/>
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:text>(</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$num"/><xsl:text>) </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="caseCond"/>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yields this output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the ambitious effort to help me :) I've taken your work as a starting point. Big thumbs up.